# Sencha-touch : how retrieve / get element register by Ext.reg()

Tags: sencha-touch, extjs

how can I retrieve a element register by the method Ext.reg?

```
prj.views.NewsSearchSection = Ext.extend(Ext.Panel, {
    fullscreen: true,
    modal: true,
    floating: true,
    layout: 'fit',
    scroll: 'vertical',

    initComponent: function() {

        this.listpanel = new Ext.Panel({
            ...
        })

        this.items = this.listpanel;

        prj.views.NewsSearchSection.superclass.initComponent.call(this);
    },

});

Ext.reg('newsSearchSection', prj.views.NewsSearchSection);
```

**I want to display/show the panel like a popup with the method show().
How can I do that?**

I tried

```
Ext.Mgr.get('newsSearchSection').show();
```

it doesn't work because Mgr doesn't exist

I need to init the component in a variable to do that?

For store it works like that:

```
Ext.regStore('newsStore',  {
    ...       
});
```

Retrieve by:

```
Ext.StoreMgr.get('newsStore').read();
```

Answer (score 1):

When you register a component to Ext you register it as an xtype.

What you would need to do is

```
var newsSearchSection = myPanel.add({xtype:'newsSearchSection'})
myPanel.setActiveItem(newsSearchSection)
```

Comment: Does the layout of the panel have to be a card layout?

Comment: Yes according to the API Docs